# How to load a style for one page in wordpress site

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles, themes

I want to create a unique style for only one of the pages on my wordpress site. Is this something I do in functions.php or in the style.css or do I need to create a new page template? For whichever option is correct, how do I target the page in question?

Comment: in `header.php` add condition:- `<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'give your page full url here'){?>

link of style sheet

<?php}else{?>

link of all other style sheets
<?php}?>`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the body_class and write css styles with the specific body_class selectors for only that page.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Put that on your opening body tag if you don't have that already.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way you can handle this is by creating a second header that pulls in this new stylesheet. Then instead of structuring your page like this:

```
<?php get_header();?>
// Body Content
<?php get_footer;?>
```

you can do this:

```
<?php get_template_part('new_header');?>
// Body Content
<?php get_footer; ?>
```

Just replace new_header with whatever the new php filename is, just leave off the extension.